# WC REST API - Using include for listing customers returns empty array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using this request, to retrieve a filtered list of customers:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?per_page=100&include=[723,2,195]
```

This has worked perfectly fine, up until a short while ago, where I've moved the site to a new server. The domain stayed exactly the same, I just switched to a different hosting provider.

The site is running perfectly well, but the customer search just doesn't work.

I can get the customer by requesting it directly:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/723
```

I can also retrieve a full list of customers, without filtering the IDs:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?per_page=100
```

But as soon as I add the `?include` parameter, the response is just an empty array.

```
200 OK: []
```

The customers are clearly there, as they can be seen in the response of the request without the include parameter.

The customer search under `WooCommerce>Customers` in the WordPress Admin Dashboard also doesn't work. Even though it shows the total customers at the bottom. So basically, the customers are there, but any kind of search / filtering results in an empty response.

I've tried to clear analytics caches and to re-import historical data, but to no avail.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with the migration of the site? Or perhaps with the `wc_customer_lookup` table? The records there seem to be fine, although I'm not sure how consistent this data is / should be.
Are there any more caches I could try to delete? Or is there some way to regenerate the customer lookup table?

The site runs on Ubuntu, using PHP8 and a managed MySQL (MariaDB) Database.

A conflict with a plugin or theme is unlikely, because it worked fine before the migration. That said, the site did run on PHP7 before this. Could there be an issue with PHP8?

Comment: any errors ? console or debug log ?

Comment: None. As far as I can tell, the server doesn't think anything is going wrong.